# React Router parent ".active" class not active when child router loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

This is how the routes are set up:

```
var RRoutes = (
<Route handler={App}>

    <Route name="home" path="/" handler={Page} />

    <Route name="portfolio" path="portfolio">
        <DefaultRoute handler={Page} />
        <Route name="portfolio.items" path=":page" handler={test} />
    </Route>

    <Route name="pages" path=":page" handler={Page} />


</Route>
);
```

When "/portfolio" page is loaded the link gets active. If the child route "portfolio.items" is loaded, the parent active link disappears.. Any suggestions how to get this to work?

Comment: looking at the `handler` properties I'm guessing you're using version 0.13.3?

Comment: Yes, "react-router": "^0.13.3"

Comment: My current work around is adding the "/portfolio" path name to app classes and use "#app.portfolio li.item.portfolio" and set fake active class..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I used "/portfolio" instead of "portfolio"

`<Link to="portfolio">`

Answered by taurose in github.
https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1684