# React Router - NavLink activeStyle or activeClassName not working for nested routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm using `react-router-dom`. In my code, `NavLink` fails to apply `activeStyle` or `activeClassName` not even on page load/reload. I've nested routes but not using redux.

**Sample Code:** [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1q4gem?file=Hello.js)

*react-router-dom version: 4.3.1*

**index.js**:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <Hello>
            <Route path="/child-a" component={ChildA} />
            <Route path="/child-b" component={ChildB} />
          </Hello>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**hello.js:**

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h5>
          <NavLink
            to="child-a"
            activeStyle={{ color:'red' }}
            exact
          >child-a</NavLink>
        </h5>
        <h5>
          <NavLink
            to="child-b"
            activeStyle={{ color:'red' }}
            exact
          >child-b</NavLink>
        </h5>
        <div>
          <div><h2>Hello</h2></div>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Router parent ".active" class not active when child router loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31902524/react-router-parent-active-class-not-active-when-child-router-loaded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting a slash before the `to` property.

Changing **hello.js** to:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h5>
          <NavLink
            to="/child-a"
            activeStyle={{ color:'red' }}
            exact
          >child-a</NavLink>
        </h5>
        <h5>
          <NavLink
            to="/child-b"
            activeStyle={{ color:'red' }}
            exact
          >child-b</NavLink>
        </h5>
        <div>
          <div><h2>Hello</h2></div>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Seems to work for me!

Comment: @AbdulRafay It's not only you. Many have faced such: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1684#issuecomment-182490928

Comment: This won't make sense if you have child paths to navigate to, will it? Suppose I am on 'example.com/orders' page and I want to navigate to 'example.com/orders/accepted' or ''example.com/orders/rejected', then appending a slash will mean "example.com/accepted".

Answer (score 0):

`NavLink` `activeStyle` doesn't work for nested routes. Since you're using `react-router-dom`, there is another property `history` which you take advantage of.

React Router [Docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history)

> history objects typically have the following properties and methods:
> location - (object) The current location.
> May have the following properties: pathname - (string) The path of the URL

**hello.js:**

```
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const activeTab = (history, path) => {
  if (history.location.pathname === path) {
    return { color: "red" };
  }
};

const Hello= ({ history }) => {
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h5>
          <Link
            to="/child-a"
            style={activeTab(history, "/child-a")}
            exact
          >child-a</Link>
        </h5>
        <h5>
          <Link
            to="/child-b"
            style={activeTab(history, "/child-b")}
            exact
          >child-b</Link>
        </h5>
        <div>
          <div><h2>Hello</h2></div>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(Hello);
```